# NSIS-How to send the parameter from command line to nsi file

Tags: nsis

I am new to NSIS script. I want to send the version number to my test.nsi file 
but it does not work. Inside  my test.nsi file, the value of version is: test.nsi.
What is the correct  syntax for this  command?

"C:\Program Files\NSIS\makensis.exe" -DVERSION=1.2.1 test.nsi

thanks,

Jdang

Answer (score 8):

The documentation is quite clear

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html

You should be using a / rather than a - to prefix the parameter name so your command becomes

```
"C:\Program Files\NSIS\makensis.exe" /DVERSION=1.2.1 test.nsi
```

Comment: I tried that option but inside the test.nsi file, I still see the value of !echo $VERSION equals test.nsi

Comment: I tried that option but inside the test.nsi file, I still see the value of !echo $VERSION equals test.nsi. What is the correct syntax to reference to VERSION variable in this case?  $VERSION ??

Comment: To reference the version value inside test.nsi file you should be using ${VERSION} and not $VERSION as it is a "define" and not a variable

Comment: Make certain that your .NSI file reference is the **last** parameter on the command line.

Comment: @BrettVeenstra You have no idea how long I spent on a problem before trying your solution.  Thank you thank you for that little tidbit that I will never forget :-)  I didn't realize the order mattered in the call.

Comment: @PaulHunt Could you please add information about `${VERSION}' in you answer? It will be more helpful:)